# Program Input from 2 sources?

Tags: bash

I am running a minecraft server in a screen session. I also am using a named pipe in order to send commands to the minecraft server from other scripts.

I can see output from the server in the screen session, however I cannot enter any. I expected this anyway since I am taking input from the named pipe.

Here's the line I run to start everything:

```
screen -S minecraft sh startup.sh
```

Here's startup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm mct
if [ ! -p mct ]; then
    mkfifo mct && chmod 0777 mct
fi

tail -f mct | java -Xincgc -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar
```

I want to be able to enter commands from the screen session and from the named pipe. Is there a way I can accomplish this? I'm just now messing around with bash scripts, been learning a lot about it today. I just can't seem how to do this.

Comment: Have you considered echoing into the FIFO?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that's what I am doing to execute commands from external scripts, I'm trying to get commands from the server's screen session (where it sends output) to execute as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to run your `tail -f mct` concurrently with a command that reads from the console and writes to the same anonymous pipe:

```
( tail -f mct & cat ) | java -Xincgc -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar
```